# AlertDialog not working in thread Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

I get an error about to much activity on main thread when I try to print to a Bluetooth printer. I tried to change it to use a thread but then my AlterDialog does not work.
Is there another way to make it work where I can display the AlterDialog?
Thanks.

```
public class PrinterFunctions{

private static void sendCommand(final Context context,final String portName, final String portSettings, final ArrayList<Byte> byteList) {

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            StarIOPort port = null;

            try {

                port = StarIOPort.getPort(portName, portSettings, 10000, context);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }


                StarPrinterStatus status = port.beginCheckedBlock();

                if (true == status.offline) {
                    throw new StarIOPortException("A printer is offline");
                }

                byte[] commandToSendToPrinter = convertFromListByteArrayTobyteArray(byteList);
                port.writePort(commandToSendToPrinter, 0,
                        commandToSendToPrinter.length);

                port.setEndCheckedBlockTimeoutMillis(30000);
                status = port.endCheckedBlock();

                if (true == status.coverOpen) {
                    throw new StarIOPortException("Printer cover is open");
                } else if (true == status.receiptPaperEmpty) {
                    throw new StarIOPortException("Receipt paper is empty");
                } else if (true == status.offline) {
                    throw new StarIOPortException("Printer is offline");
                }
            } catch (StarIOPortException e) {
                Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Ok", null);
                AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                alert.setTitle("Failure");
                alert.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.show();
            } finally {
                if (port != null) {
                    try {
                        StarIOPort.releasePort(port);
                    } catch (StarIOPortException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }.start();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update UI in other thread (not main thread), you must use `Handler`

```
private Handler handler=new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    dialog.setNegativeButton("Ok", null);
                    AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                    alert.setTitle("Failure");
                    alert.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                    alert.setCancelable(false);
                    alert.show();
                }
            });
        };
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: will I add this between catch (StarIOPortException e) { and finally in my above code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code in your exception catcher:

```
    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Ok", null);
                AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                alert.setTitle("Failure");
                alert.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.show();
            }
        });
```

OR

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                      dialog.setNegativeButton("Ok", null);
                      AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                      alert.setTitle("Failure");
                      alert.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                      alert.setCancelable(false);
                      alert.show();
                    }
                });
            };
        }.start();
```

Comment: I will create a new thread just for the alert dialog inside the existing thread?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I just want to help those who will end up here.

*I will create a new thread just for the alert dialog inside the existing thread?*

Technically you're not creating a new thread but `calling` the Main thread to create your alert dialog because you're currently inside you're background thread.

So for your dialog to pop up you need the Main thread execute your alert dialog command.

**try to replace**

```
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Ok", null);
                AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                alert.setTitle("Failure");
                alert.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.show();
```

**with**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Ok", null);
                AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                alert.setTitle("Failure");
                alert.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.show();
    });
```

**or you can use a handler**

`protected Handler handler = new Handler(Loop.getMainLooper)`

```
handler.post(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Ok", null);
                AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
                alert.setTitle("Failure");
                alert.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.show();
    });
```